# What is the plural form of "the name of which"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Consider we have a sentence:

> I have a box named "A".

rewritten as such:

> I have a box, the name of which is "A".

How should we rewrite the sentence if now there is more than one "item"?

> I have three boxes, named "A", "B", and "C".

Is the sentence below grammatical? :

> I have three boxes, the names of them are "A", "B", and "C".

Comment: Technically, in your last example "I have ..." and "the names of them are ..." are independent clauses, and so should be separated with a period, colon or semi-colon. "I have three boxes; the names of them are 'A', 'B', and 'C'."

Comment: @Jay Do you mean to say that "The names of them are.." is grammatically valid?

Comment: Yes, "the names ..." is valid. PopMachine and Rudra give other gramatically-correct options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is still "which" in the plural.

The following sentence is grammatical:

> I have three boxes, the names of which are "A", "B", and "C".

Answer (score 4):

In your last sentence, you should replace *"them"* with *"which"*; so it becomes,

> I have three boxes, the names of **which** are A, B and C.

Or, you could simply say,

> - I have three boxes, namely A, B and C.
> - I have three boxes, named A, B and C.
> - I have three boxes, A, B and C.

Comment: A colon in the last bullet would be ultimately clear.